# Gephi and NetworkX return different average clustering coefficient for same graph

Tags: graph-theory, networkx, gephi

I calculated average clustering coefficient using both Gephi and NetworkX. For the same graph NetworkX gave 0.2399 while Gephi gave 0.644.

1. Why is it different ?
2. How do NetworkX and Gephi calculate average clustering coefficient ?
3. In case of disconnected components specifically; how do NetworkX and Gephi calculate the coefficient ?

Comment: [link] (https://github.com/gephi/gephi/issues/625)
Is it because of considering the clustering coefficient to be 0 or 1 for nodes of degree less than 2 ??

Comment: Yes... networkx makes the clustering coefficient to be 0 for nodes with degree less than 2 and averages over all the nodes. 
While Gephi doesn't count the nodes at all that are having degree less than 2 and computes average clustering only for nodes with degree >= 2

Comment: I tried to remove the nodes with degree less than two and I still get different results from gephi and from networkx. The difference is smaller than the one without removing those nodes but still it is quite off.

Answer (score 0):

just to mention that networkx's average_clustering has a parameter named ***count_zeros***. [average_clustering documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cluster.average_clustering.html#networkx.algorithms.cluster.average_clustering)

Its default value is True which means it will take zero-clustering node into account. You can set it to False and see if it returns the same value as Gephi.

Comment: This is more suited as a comment rather than an answer.